# Replace Component in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, layout-manager

I created a Class that extends from JPanel which layout property is GridBagLayout. I basically need to display an array of JLabels (grid) but i'm not able to replace a component once it's created. I've tried to remove the component that I want to change, and then place the new one but the result is weird. For example i've created an array of 10x10 JLabels and want to replace position[0][0] and position[9][9] with this code:

```
//At first i have the jpanel layout completely filled

this.remove(0);
this.add((JLabel) start, 0);  //This was created with GridBagLayout.gridx = 0 and GridBagLayout.gridy = 0 and it's fine

this.remove(99);
this.add((JLabel) end, 99); //This was created with GridBagLayout.gridx = 9 and GridBagLayout.gridy = 9 and it's out of grid
this.revalidate();
```

But only position[0][0] looks fine. What should i do to replace a component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem by using:

```
this.setComponentZOrder(newItem, 0);
```

So, I actually didn't remove the object on Jpanel but I placed the new one over the old object.

Answer (score 6):

In `GridBagLayout`, each component is associated with `GridBagConstraints`.  Simple removing a component and replacing it with a component at the same position won't work, as the new component will receive a new `GridBagConstraints`

What you can do, however, is get the constraints associated with a give component.

```
Component toRemove = getComponent(0);
GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout)getLayout();
GridBagConstraints gbc = layout.getConstraints();
remove(toRemove);
add(new JLabel("Happy"), gbc, 0);
```

This will add the component using the same constraints as those used by the component you are removing.

This of course all assumes that you are assigning the `gridx`/`gridy` constraints...

Comment: @System.exit: Also consider updating the component in place.

Comment: I tried your code but the result is exactly the same but thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer i do use gridx / gridy